# Temporary tables using RMySQL

Tags: sql, r, temp-tables, rmysql

Is there a way to create a temporary table using the `RMySQL` package?  If so what is the correct way to do it?  In particular I am trying to write a dataframe from my **R** session to the temporary table.  I have several processes running in parallel and I don't want to worry about name conflicts, that's why I want to make them temporary so they are only visible to each individual session.  The solution should somehow involve `dbWritetable` and not `dbSendQuery("create temporary table tbl;")`.

NOTE: I found some stuff on the net that suggests creating a temporary table manually using `dbSendQuery(con, "create temporary table x (x int)")` and then simply overriding it with `dbWriteTable()`.  This does not work.

Comment: Does running `dbSendQuery(con,"COMMIT")` after your `create temporary table` line fix things? Courtesy of: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-db/2009q1/000575.html

Comment: After creating the temp table, try `dbWriteTable(..., append=TRUE, overwrite=FALSE)`.  Also maybe use another program to connect to the database and check that the table is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this type of job, I would avoid reinventing the wheel and use

https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/

By default, it is for sqlite, but it also works for MySQL (which I never tried). This package is rock-solid and well documented.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your mysql account restriction can you not do

```
dbSendQuery(con, "create temporary table x (x int);")
dbSendQuery(con, "drop temporary table x;")
```

etc..

Comment: i should have been more specific in my question. sorry. updated

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a [known issue in RMySQL](https://github.com/jeffreyhorner/RMySQL/issues/10).  Your best bet might be to write the data to a temporary file and then construct your own `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` statement, using `RMySQL::mysqlWriteTable` as a guide.

For bonus points, if you can patch RMySQL::mysqlWriteTable to work with tempfiles, send a pull request to the [github repo](https://github.com/jeffreyhorner/RMySQL/blob/master/R/MySQLSupport.R).